# How to interpret complex strings as graph properties when reading a graphML file using `boost::read_graphml`?

Tags: c++, graph, boost, graphml, boost-property-map

I have a graph type where each Vertex carries a `std::vector<int>` as a property.

```cpp
struct VertexProperties {
  std::vector<int> numbers;
};
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperties>;
```

I wrote an example object of my graph type to a GraphML file using `boost::write_graphml`. To do so, I used `boost::make_transform_value_property_map` to convert the `std::vector<int>` property to a `std::string`. The GraphML file has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key id="key0" for="node" attr.name="numbers" attr.type="string" />
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected" parse.nodeids="free" parse.edgeids="canonical" parse.order="nodesfirst">
    <node id="n0">
      <data key="key0">1 2 3 </data>
    </node>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

Now I would like to read the file back in to reobtain the graph (in a different program) using `boost::read_graphml`. To do so, it is necessary to create a `boost::dynamic_properties` object and add to that a property map that can understand the information found in the GraphML file and set the correct vertex property accordingly.

How can the latter property map be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by writing a custom property map class template `TranslateStringPMap` that wraps an existing property map and takes two function objects that convert between strings and the wrapped map's value type.

File `translate_string_pmap.hpp`:

```cpp
#ifndef TRANSLATE_STRING_PMAP_H
#define TRANSLATE_STRING_PMAP_H

#include <string>

#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>

template <typename PMap, typename ToString, typename FromString>
class TranslateStringPMap {
public:
  using category = boost::read_write_property_map_tag;
  using key_type = typename boost::property_traits<PMap>::key_type;
  using reference = std::string;
  using value_type = std::string;

  TranslateStringPMap(
      PMap wrapped_pmap, ToString to_string, FromString from_string)
      : wrapped_pmap{wrapped_pmap},
        to_string{to_string},
        from_string{from_string} {}

  auto friend get(TranslateStringPMap const& translator, key_type const& key)
      -> value_type {
    return translator.to_string(get(translator.wrapped_pmap, key));
  }

  auto friend put(
      TranslateStringPMap const& translator, key_type const& key,
      value_type const& value) -> void {
    boost::put(translator.wrapped_pmap, key, translator.from_string(value));
  }

private:
  PMap wrapped_pmap;
  ToString to_string;
  FromString from_string;
};

#endif
```

By customizing the conversion function objects `to_string` and `from_string`, `TranslateStringPMap` can be added to a `boost::dynamic_properties` object to facilitate reading and writing of arbitrary graph property types. The following file gives a usage example.

File `graph_rw.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/dynamic_property_map.hpp>

#include "translate_string_pmap.hpp"

struct VertexProperties {
  std::vector<int> numbers;
};
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperties>;

auto vec2str(std::vector<int> const& vec) -> std::string {
  auto str = std::string{};
  for (auto number : vec) {
    str += std::to_string(number) += " ";
  }
  return str;
}

auto str2vec(std::string const& str) -> std::vector<int> {
  auto strs = std::stringstream{str};
  auto number = 0;
  auto vec = std::vector<int>{};
  while (strs >> number) {
    vec.push_back(number);
  }
  return vec;
}

auto write_my_graphml(Graph& graph, std::ofstream& output_stream) -> void {
  auto dprops = boost::dynamic_properties{};
  dprops.property(
      "numbers",
      TranslateStringPMap{
          boost::get(&VertexProperties::numbers, graph), vec2str, str2vec});
  boost::write_graphml(output_stream, graph, dprops);
}

auto read_my_graphml(std::ifstream& input_stream) -> Graph {
  auto graph = Graph{};
  auto dprops = boost::dynamic_properties{};
  dprops.property(
      "numbers",
      TranslateStringPMap{
          boost::get(&VertexProperties::numbers, graph), vec2str, str2vec});
  boost::read_graphml(input_stream, graph, dprops);
  return graph;
}

auto main() -> int {
  {
    auto graph1 = Graph{};
    boost::add_vertex(VertexProperties{{1, 2, 3}}, graph1);
    auto out_stream = std::ofstream{"graph1.gml"};
    write_my_graphml(graph1, out_stream);
  }
  {
    auto in_stream = std::ifstream{"graph1.gml"};
    auto graph2 = read_my_graphml(in_stream);
    auto out_stream = std::ofstream{"graph2.gml"};
    write_my_graphml(graph2, out_stream);
  }
}
```